# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException Из-за ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Есть следующая проблема- На мобильном приложении есть 1 активити и 2 фрагмента.

Первый фрагмент- главное меню. В нём есть список уровней в виде различных ImageView и навешанных на них слушателей. По клику на уровень, открывается второй фрагмент со списком заданий в этом уровне. Список заданий отображается в `ViewPager`'e . В качестве адаптера использую собственную имплементацию `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` . Но вот в чем проблема- если часто переходить со второго фрагмента на первый и обратно посредством нажатия кнопки "Назад" (или `onBackPressed()`, это не имеет значения), то приложение крашится с ошибкой

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e00e0 (ru.timuruktus.febree:id/tasksFragmentViewPager) for fragment TaskFragment{ab8ac48 #6 id=0x7f0e00e0}
```

Что уже только не перепробовал- и пытался id присвоить ViewPager'у и чистил проект и изменял адаптер так и сяк, и уже кучу всего, что я уже не помню. Ничего не помогает. Собственно, вот все необходимые вставки кода:

**StepsFragment.java (Первый фрагмент)**

```
public class StepsFragment extends Fragment implements BaseStepsFragment{


    public View rootView;
    private ImageView[][] taskIcons = new ImageView[BLOCK_COUNT][BLOCK_STEPS_COUNT];
    private TextView[][] taskNames = new TextView[BLOCK_COUNT][BLOCK_STEPS_COUNT];
    private Context context;
    private BaseStepsPresenter presenter;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        rootView =
                inflater.inflate(R.layout.steps_fragment, container, false);
        Log.d("mytag", "Creating new fragment");
        context = rootView.getContext();
        presenter = new StepsPresenter(this);
        initAllViews();
        //MainActivity.showSplashScreen();
        presenter.onCreate();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageAndText(Step step){
        int blockNum = step.getBlock();
        int stepInBlockNum = step.getIdInBlock();
        taskIcons[blockNum][stepInBlockNum].setImageResource(step.getFullPath(context));
        Drawable drawable = taskIcons[blockNum][stepInBlockNum].getDrawable();
        if(drawable instanceof Animatable){
            ((Animatable) drawable).start();
        }
        taskNames[blockNum][stepInBlockNum].setText(step.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String title = context.getResources().getString(R.string.steps_fragment);
        MainPresenter.changeToolbarTitle(title);
    }

    private void initAllViews(){
        taskIcons[0][0] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step11);
        taskIcons[0][1] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step12);
        taskIcons[0][2] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step13);
        taskIcons[0][3] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step14);
        taskIcons[0][4] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step15);
        taskIcons[1][0] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step21);
        taskIcons[1][1] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step22);
        taskIcons[1][2] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step23);
        taskIcons[1][3] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step24);
        taskIcons[1][4] = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step25);

        for(int blockNum = 0; blockNum < BLOCK_COUNT; blockNum++){
            for(int stepNum = 0; stepNum < BLOCK_STEPS_COUNT; stepNum++){
                taskIcons[blockNum][stepNum].setOnClickListener(getImageListener(blockNum, stepNum));
            }
        }

        taskNames[0][0] = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step11Name);
        taskNames[0][1] = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step12Name);
        taskNames[0][2] = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step13Name);
        taskNames[0][3] = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step14Name);
        taskNames[0][4] = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step15Name);
        taskNames[1][0] = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step21Name);
        taskNames[1][1] = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step22Name);
        taskNames[1][2] = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step23Name);
        taskNames[1][3] = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step24Name);
        taskNames[1][4] = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.step25Name);
    }

    @NonNull
    private View.OnClickListener getImageListener(int blockNum, int stepNum){
        return v -> presenter.onStepClick(blockNum, stepNum);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("mytag", "onDestroy() in StepsFragment");
        //presenter.onDestroy();
        //presenter = null;
    }


}
```

**TasksFragment.java (Второй фрагмент)**

```
public class TasksFragment extends Fragment implements BaseTasksView {

    public static final String ARGS_BLOCK = "Block";
    public static final String ARGS_STEP = "Step";

    private int block;
    private int step;
    private View rootView;
    private BaseTasksPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView  = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.tasks_fragment, container, false);
        presenter = new TasksPresenter();
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        HashMap<String, Integer> info = (HashMap<String, Integer>) args.getSerializable(ARG_INFO);
        block = info.get(ARGS_BLOCK);
        step = info.get(ARGS_STEP);
        presenter.onCreate(this, block, step);
        ImageView tasksBackArrow = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tasksBackArrow);
        tasksBackArrow.setOnClickListener(v -> presenter.onBackArrowClick());
        TextView tasksStepName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tasksStepName);
        tasksStepName.setText(presenter.getStepName());

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("mytag", "onDestroy() is TasksFragment");
        //presenter.onDestroy();
        //presenter = null;
        // TODO: Если раскоментить 2 строчки выше- появляется баг. Понять почему
    }


    @Override
    public void showTasks(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tasksFragmentViewPager);
        FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
        PagerAdapter textPagerAdapter = new TasksFragmentAdapter(tasks, fm);
        pager.setAdapter(textPagerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getFragment() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

**TasksPresenter.java (Презентер второго фрагмента)**

```
class TasksPresenter implements BaseTasksPresenter {


    private BaseTasksView view;
    private BaseTasksModel model;
    private int blockNum;
    private int stepNum;

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Task> onCreate(BaseTasksView view, int blockNum, int stepNum) {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = new TasksModel();
        Log.d("mytag", "onCreate blockNum = " + blockNum + " step = " + stepNum);
        ArrayList<Task> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        this.blockNum = blockNum;
        this.stepNum = stepNum;
        addSubscription(model.getTaskByStep(blockNum, stepNum).subscribe(new Observer<Task>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                view.showTasks(tasks);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.d("mytag", "TasksPresenter.onCreate some error" + e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Task task) {
                tasks.add(task);
                Log.d("mytag", "Next task");
            }
        }));

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackArrowClick() {
        view.getFragment().getActivity().onBackPressed();
        //MainPresenter.changeFragment(new StepsFragment(), DONT_ADD_TO_BACKSTACK, DONT_REFRESH, DONT_HIDE_TOOLBAR);
    }

    @Override
    public String getStepName() {
        return model.getStepByNumber(blockNum, stepNum);
    }

    @Override
    public void addSubscription(Subscription subscription) {
        allSubscriptions.add(subscription);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        allSubscriptions.unsubscribe();
        Log.d("mytag", "onDestroy() in TasksPresenter");
    }
```

}

**Код смены фрагментов (Находится в презентере главной активити)**

```
public static void changeFragmentWithInfo(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack, boolean refresh,
                                      boolean hideToolbar, HashMap<String, Integer> info){
        Class fragmentClass = fragment.getClass();
        if(currentFragmentClass != null) {
            if (fragmentClass.equals(currentFragmentClass) && !refresh) {
                //Log.d("mytag", "MainPresenter.changeFragment() already that fragment");
                return;
            }
        }
        currentFragmentClass = fragment.getClass();
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        if(addToBackStack) {
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        if(info != null) {
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable(ARG_INFO, info);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
        }
        changeToolbarVisibility(hideToolbar);
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
```

tasks_fragment.xml (Разметка второго фрагмента)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tasks_fragment_background_color"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tasksBackArrow"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tasksStepName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tasksBackArrow"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/tasksFragmentViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"></android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Полный стэктрэйс ошибки:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: ru.timuruktus.febree, PID: 5193
                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e00e0 (ru.timuruktus.febree:id/tasksFragmentViewPager) for fragment TaskFragment{ab8ac48 #6 id=0x7f0e00e0}
                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:965)
                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                                        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1537)
                                                                        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:562)
                                                                        at android.support.v13.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:176)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1268)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:273)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:860)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:672)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:605)
                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:846)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:742)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Comment: ПОпробуйте вместо `FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();` так: `FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();`

Comment: Жесть, а я ведь ещё думал, что у меня там нигде FragmentManager не создается, черт, поэтому пренебрег ответами, которые уже были  даны на этот вопрос ранее..

Comment: Т.е. помогло: =)

Comment: Ага, помогло) Несколько часов потратил на решение проблемы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во фрагментах, для любых действий с фрагментами вложенными, т.е. в т.ч. в случае с `ViewPager` во фрагменте, надо использовать `FragmentManager` фрагмента, который надо получать методом `getChildFragmentManager()`, т.е. в вашем случае надо заменить

> FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getFragmentManager();

на

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
```

Answer (score 1):

Дополню ответ ЮрийСПб, у меня данная ошибка вылетала пока я не стал устанавливать код фрагменту хардкодом (была генерация id для view - заменил на 1 - см код):

```
view = new LinearLayout(context);
view.setLayoutParams(newViewGroup.LayoutParams
    (ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
view.setId(1);
view.setPadding(0,10,0,0);

fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(1, VideoFragment.newInstance(text)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```